# 2gp: Problem with adding custom fields to Territory2 object via DX Unpackaged Metadata feature when creating package version

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, territory-management, 2gp

We are developing 2gp which heavily uses Enterprise Territory Management feature. And as part of post install configuration subscribers should manually create some custom fields with predefined names on Territory2 object.

In order to cover such functionality with Apex tests inside our 2gp, we are trying to use 'Unpackaged Metadata' feature as described in DX guide (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_unpackaged_md.htm).

Few months ago we solved similar challenge for this 2gp with profiles created at subscriber org level but still needed for our packaged tests.

So following exact same approach, we've added metadata with Territory2 fields to already existent unpackaged folder (by adding objects subfolder next to profiles subfolder). But when creating package version with validation we are still getting tests failures complaining about unknown custom fields on Territory2 object (like no difference whether we provide Territory2 fields in unpackaged metadata or nor). Example of a test failure error message: `System.SObjectException: Invalid field Color__c for Territory2`

Has anyone already tried adding custom fields to standard objects via unpackaged metadata? Has someone tried the same for Territory2 object? Any help or advice would be appreciated.